# Crear cname debian 10 vps

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, dns, certificado-ssl

compre un ssl en [swhosting](https://www.swhosting.com/es) con un vps, sin embargo no se mucho de redes y me pide que valide por medio del dns  alguien sabe como hacerlo? con mucho trabajo logre enlazar el [dominio](http://tortilleriafonte.com) al vps con bind9 sin embargo no se como hacer lo del ssl, el vps es debian 10 con nginx
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir a tu proveedor de dominios, crear un registro **CNAME** y en el contenido o valor poner el alias, y en a donde apunta o servidor, poner el servidor.

Comment: Se necesita una explicación con más detalle, más amplia.